# Using ManagementObjectSearcher causes AppDomainUnloadedException warning from MSTest

Tags: c#, wmi

This code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WmiTest() {
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM CIM_OperatingSystem")) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Result in:
*System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.*

from MSTest.

I know that this is usually caused by objects not disposed or threads still running but what is there to stop/free here?

**EDIT:**

The above instantiation is the same as:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope();  
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_OperatingSystem");
```

All that is neccesary to trigger *System.AppDomainUnloadedException* is this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void WmiTest() {
    var scope = new ManagementScope();
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?